# Efficiency: JS Slider VS animated Gif

Tags: javascript, css, animated-gif

I have been asked to build a website with an area on each page that is 1600 X 610 px, where images slide across (3-4 images, changing/sliding every 10 seconds). I have done this before with a JS slider.

It has been suggested that maybe it would be more 'efficient' for the image to be an animated gif, rather than a JS controlled slider.

The website will not be otherwise very heavy with regards to code or images. Hard to quantise, but which solution (JS slider or 1600 X 610 gif) in terms of memory and speed would be the most efficient? How can I compare\calculate the trade offs for different size sliding image boxes?

Are there any other issues that I should be ware of with either solution?

Thanks

Lee

Comment: Compressed JPEGs are WAY lighter than a GIF animation of that proportion. Suppose you want to add another "slide", you'll have to remake the whole GIF animation, even if you have a designer to do this, why the trouble? JavaScript approach is way better, more flexible and loads quicker.

Comment: Also keep in mind that GIF supports a max of 256 colors, so the quality is lower...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely go with JS, gif will be to heavy and using gif you'll lose all the flexibility. In terms of performance you won't notice any difference, but in terms of loading of the page it will take much more time if you'll use gif. Besides it'll be much easier to create a JS animation than to generate gif.

Comment: Thanks for your input. With regards to generating the gif, I have an artist who can do this for me, so difficulty of generating a gif is negligible for me.